# Vue Router Webpack Dot in Params

Tags: url, webpack, vue.js, parameters

I'm creating an app with NodeJS/Express for the back and VueJS for the Front using Vue Cli and webpack.

I'd like to know if there is a way to allow dot in params for my routes.

Here is what I get when i try with no config

[Cannot GET /t/firstname.lastname](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rbXmF.png)

Here is my /src/main.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'

import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import VueResource from 'vue-resource'
import VueAutosize from 'vue-autosize'

import Main from './components/Main.vue'
import Signin from './components/Signin.vue'

// We want to apply VueResource and VueRouter
// to our Vue instance
Vue.use(VueRouter)
Vue.use(VueResource)
Vue.use(VueAutosize)

const router = new VueRouter({
  history: true
})

// Pointing routes to the components they should use
router.map({
  '/t/:person': {
    component: Main
  },
  '/signin': {
    component: Signin
  }
})

router.beforeEach(function (transition) {
  if (transition.to.path === '/signin' && window.localStorage.length !== 0) {
    transition.redirect('/')
  } else if (transition.to.path === '/' && window.localStorage.length === 0) {
    transition.redirect('/signin')
  } else {
    transition.next()
  }
})

// Any invalid route will redirect to home
router.redirect({
  '*': '/404'
})

router.start(App, '#app')
```

Comment: I believe that vue-router converts param in url into a javascript object, so the use of a point isn't allowed. But I tested with other punctuation marks and it's ok.
You can use regexp or optionnal parameter if you want > [https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/blob/9649929b3646954c7b59d149c570c3d0a96379c9/examples/route-matching/app.js](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/blob/9649929b3646954c7b59d149c570c3d0a96379c9/examples/route-matching/app.js)

Comment: @utiiz Did you find a solution? I have the same problem.

Comment: How is this related to Webpack?

Comment: This is a webpack problem they have a rule which if a uri have a dot then it is a file, it happen on express dev server.

Answer (score 1):

I was dealing with the same issue, even I'm late to the conversation maybe somebody will find useful the solution I found.

It appears to be webpack's fault.

If using vue-cli's webpack template you'll need to configure a proxy for the routes you need. For example in your case you'll need to add this to the `config/index.js` file:

```
...
dev: {
  ...
  proxyTable: {
    '/t/*.*': { // this will match all urls with dots after '/t/'
      target: 'http://localhost:8080/',  // send to webpack dev server
      router: function (req) {
        req.url = 'index.html'  // Send to vue app
      }
    }
    // Any other routes you need to bypass should go here.
  }
  ...
},
...
```

This way webpack will proxy all requests to that url and don't treat these as files.

Answer (score 0):

Add `/something` after params
eg: in your route

```
{
  path: your-route/:paramname/something",
  component: somecomponent,
}
```

After this, you should be able to access the route using `this.$route.params.paramname`

Answer (score 0):

do below setting in webpack

```
devServer: {
      historyApiFallback: {
          disableDotRule: true
      }
 }
```